# How to group output and create columns from results

Tags: mysql

My query almost outputs the required data, but not in the format I'm after. It is producing a line item per trainer as the wage_type in not unique (can be 3 types), and the amounts can be anything.

```sql
SELECT 
    trainerid, name,
    wage_period, wage_type,
    amount,
    SUM(amount)
FROM 
    course_local_staff_wages
INNER JOIN 
    course_local_trainers ON course_local_staff_wages.trainerid = course_local_trainers.userid
WHERE 
    wage_period = '11-2021'
GROUP BY 
    Trainerid, Name, Wage_Period, wage_type, amount
```

I am getting the individual lines per `trainerid`, but would like the output to be a single line per trainer with the output as follows:

```
Trainerid, Name, Wage_Period, Invoice Amt, Trainer Fees, Other, Total (of the 3 columns Trainer  Fees, Other)
```

Something like this:

```
Trainer Id  Name         Wage_Period InvoiceAmt  TrainerFees  Other  Total
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
12345       Jack Sparrow 11-2021     21.10       1000         100    1121.10
45632       Tony White   11-2021     10          900          50     960

Grand Total 2081.10
```

The Grand Total is a nice to have.

I'm assuming a subquery to do it based on the initial results, but I don't have a clue how to achieve this.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.